# "Zum abendessen"

Tags: noun, adverb

What is the translation of these two sentences ?

> I drink juice **with** dinner.
>
> I eat pork **for** dinner.

When we wanna say "for dinner" and "with dinner",can we use "zum abendessen" for both ?

Comment: Yes you can do that.

Comment: So how can we understand wich one is meant?

Comment: So what should make the difference?

Comment: Do you eat pork with dinner? Do you drink juice for dinner?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Drinking juice *for* dinner would imply the juice **is** the dinner (maybe a diet). "Zum Abendessen" doesn't distinguish between these cases (for/with).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In either case you use 'zum Abendessen'

> Ich esse Schweinefleisch zum Abendessen.
>   Ich trinke Saft zum Abendessen.

and people will understand that that you're drinking juice **with** dinner.

If you're on a diet and want to emphasize the fact the juice is the whole dinner, you could say

> Ich trinke Saft **als** Abendessen.